# Boost Interthread Communication

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have to implement boost inter-thread communication. Consider following code:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
void threadA()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "From thread A" << std::endl;
        Sleep(3000); //pretend to do the work
    }
}

void threadB()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "From thread B" << std::endl;
        Sleep(3000); //pretend to do the work
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread *th1 = new boost::thread(&threadA);
    boost::thread *th2 = new boost::thread(&threadB);
    th1->join();
    th2->join();
    delete th1;
    delete th2;
}
```

If I run the above code, it will spawn both thread. What I want to do is start the `threadA` and send some message to `threadB`, which upon receiving will start the thread. Or More Generally, How can I handle the communication if both of these thread run independently ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways.

- use a condition variable (aka. event)
- use a concurrent queue (messages, e.g.) or more generically, semaphores
- use lockfree concurrent data structures

Boost provides implementation of all of the above.

Comment: one way would be implementing a global variable and checking them in thread. How can I use semaphore, lockfree queues in my existing code.?

Comment: In any which way you would use them in other languages/platforms. They are really language-agnostic concepts. Just read some docs (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/lockfree.html, or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref). And, combining lockfree queues with semaphores makes zero sense.

Comment: 'implementing a global variable and checking them in thread' - terribru for most purposes.  There are rare cases for such communication, eg. an atomic 'AppClosing=true' for all threads to check occasionally, but pretty hopeless for general inter-thread comms where polling is a waste of CPU, memory-bandwidth and energy, (unless your office is really cold).